# Unit test for method retrieving data from CacheManger using for loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, ehcache

I have a method that with retrieve persons from a next webapi and store in cache and i want to fetch the same cached data from the cache Manager. I am having difficulties to write unit test for this method. 
Any help is highly appreciated

```
import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.CacheManager;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "cacheManager")
private CacheManager cacheManager;

*public List<Person> fallbackPersons() {
      List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Cache.Entry<Object, Object> entry :cacheManager.getCache("person"){ 
        data = (List<Person>) entry.getValue();
        }
    return data;
}*
```

Answer (score 4):

You can mock the CacheManager, stub it and verify result as below:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class PersonsServiceTest {

        @Mock
        private CacheManager cacheManager;

        @InjectMocks
        PersonsService service = new PersonsService();

        @Before
        public void setup() {
             MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void fallbackPersonsWithNonEmptyCache() {
            List<Person> persons = Collections.singletonList(new Person());  // create person object as your Person class definition
            // mock cache entry
            Cache.Entry <Object, Object> entry = Mockito.mock(Cache.Entry.class);

            // do stubbing
            Mockito.when(entry.getValue()).thenReturn(persons);
            Mockito.when(cacheManager.getCache(Matchers.anyString()))
                    .thenReturn(entry);

            // execute
            List<Person> persons = service.fallbackPersons();

            // verify
            Assert.assertNotNull(persons);
            Assert.assertFalse(persons.isEmpty());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you response.   below line should return the cache instead of emptyList 
    Mockito.when(cacheManager.getCache(Matchers.anyString()))
                    .thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());                                               
  Also I am still getting the NullPointerExcetpion from from line                                                                         for (Cache.Entry<Object, Object> entry :cacheManager.getCache("person"){

Comment: @suraz i have updated the example, please have a look!

Comment: I checked with your updated example @yogen but i am getting the same error of NullPointerException.

Comment: @suraz assert or debug before execute if `cacheManager` has been mocked.. also make sure you have `@RunWith(MockitoRunner.class)` because that is telling to enable mock annotations.. if still getting same error, tell me the difference on code i gave you and you have.

Comment: thank you for you quick response.it help me to figure out the solution. Actually, i had to mock every single step to pass the test. Below i have posted the solution hopefully it might somebody.

Comment: @suraz makes sense.. good to hear it is working for you.. :) pls upvote/accept if it helped you :)

Comment: Actually, I am new in commenting and posting in stack overflow so I haven't yet accessed to make the vote or accept. Can you pls upvote/accept mine so that I can get that access soon?

Comment: @suraz  sure!! Welcome to stackoverflow community :)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Unit testing**

If your intention is to unit test the public method `fallbackPersons` by mocking `CacheManager`, I strongly recommend to change the style you inject the cacheManager bean, by using constructor injection:

```
import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.CacheManager;

@Service    
public class PersonsService {
    private final CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Autowired
    public PersonsService(@Qualifier(value = "cacheManager") CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    public List<Person> fallbackPersons() {
        List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Cache.Entry<Object, Object> entry : cacheManager.getCache("person")) { 
            data = (List<Person>) entry.getValue();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

This class is now very easy to unit test by injecting the mock of `CacheManager` and program its behavior, you will not need to bootstrap the Spring context (to apply @Autowired), or use Powermock library to access private properties.

Example of unit test:

```
public class PersonsServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void fallbackPersonsWithEmptyCache() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = Mockito.mock(CacheManager.class);
        Mockito.when(cacheManager.getCache(Matchers.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());

        PersonsService service = new PersonsService(cacheManager);
        List<Person> persons = service.fallbackPersons();
        Assert.assertNotNull(persons);
        Assert.assertTrue(persons.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

**2. Integration testing**

If you actually would like to test your service with real cache manager implementation from Spring, then you should look into example on how to use `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests` or `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` classes provided by Spring Framework. They will allow you to initialize true Spring context and inject real CacheManager implementations like EhCahce, etc.

Comment: Thank you for you response.   below line should return the cache instead of emptyList          Mockito.when(cacheManager.getCache(Matchers.anyString()))
                    .thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());                                               
  Also I am still getting the NullPointerExcetpion from from line                                                                         
                                                                                                                           
  for (Cache.Entry<Object, Object> entry :cacheManager.getCache("person"){

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution to my problem.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Slf4j
public class CacheTest {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    PersonService personService;

    @Mock
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void fallbackMCCsWithNonEmptyCache() {

        List<Person> persons = Collections.singletonList(new Person());

        Iterator<Cache.Entry <Object, Object>> cacheIterator = 
        Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
        Cache <Object, Object> cache = Mockito.mock(Cache.class);
        Cache.Entry <Object, Object> entry = Mockito.mock(Cache.Entry.class);
        Mockito.when(cacheManager.getCache(Mockito.anyString()))
        .thenReturn(cache);
        Mockito.when(cache.iterator()).thenReturn(cacheIterator);
        List<Person> personList = personService.fallbackPersons();
        Assert.assertNotNull(personList);
        Assert.assertTrue(personList.isEmpty());
    }
}
```